# Do declarator blocks work on roles when they are unit-declared?

Tags: documentation, raku

They apparently don't, if there's a "use" clause before, like here:

```
use Foo;

#| Why for Baz
unit role Baz does foo;

method quux { "quux"}
```

Then

```
use Baz;

say Baz.WHY;
```

yields:

```
No documentation available for type 'Baz'.
```

Is this a bug, or am I doing something wrong here?

*Update*: reported [as a bug here](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/3521)

Comment: Feels like a bug to me.

Comment: @ElizabethMattijsen problem is, it seems to affect the whole role; no way to use it on any other function.

Comment: [In a 2018.04.1 Rakudo they don't work on *any* roles](https://glot.io/snippets/fl3ri2wfrc).